# Cómo quitar vista en blanco al tratar de mostrar una url en el navegador

Tags: android, android-studio

En esta oportunidad quiero mostrar una url, pero como la voy a mostrar en el navegador, no uso un WebView, tampoco uso un Layout asociado al Activity que he creado, sin embargo aun así al lanzarlo se abre la url en el navegador pero por debajo queda activado una vista en blanco, creo que al no tener el setContentView(R.layout.***); en uso no debería mostrar esta vista en blanco pero igual lo hace, como puedo evitarlo. A continuación mi código :

En el MainActivity lanzo la actividad con:

```
Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tour.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
```

La Activity es la siguiente:

```
public class Activity_Tour360 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Muestra contenido en el navegador
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Además de abrir la url, que es lo quiero, me muestra la siguiente vista que es lo que quiero evitar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por que no abres la url directamente desde el MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que finalizar la actividad utilizando `finish()` para evitar la pantalla en blanco:

```
public class Activity_Tour360 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Muestra contenido en el navegador
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);

        // finalizamos la actividad que muestra la pantalla en blanco
        finish();
    }
}
```

Aunque no entiendo porque simplemente, en vez de inicializar la actividad `Activity_Tour360` que solo ejecuta un intent, ejecutas directamente en `Intent`.

En vez de:

```
Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tour.class);
startActivity(i3);
```

Ejecutas el `Intent` directamente:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: :D Gracias lo había olvidado, pero la segunda opción si está mejor.